# Create Image then convert to code in reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

i am new in web design using reactjs, i have question about code that make image like this

```
<path fill="#06C755" d="M106.214,4.621h-7.829c-1.201,0-2.175,0.972-2.175,2.171v28.894l-22.288-30.1 c-0.052-0.077-0.11-0.15-0.172-0.219c-0.004-0.006-0.009-0.011-0.014-0.016c-0.041-0.045-0.083-0.09-0.127-0.133 c-0.014-0.013-0.028-0.024-0.041-0.036c-0.038-0.034-0.076-0.067-0.116-0.098c-0.018-0.015-0.038-0.029-0.057-0.043 c-0.036-0.027-0.075-0.053-0.112-0.078c-0.022-0.013-0.044-0.026-0.066-0.04C73.178,4.901,73.14,4.879,73.1,4.859 c-0.023-0.011-0.045-0.022-0.069-0.033c-0.041-0.019-0.082-0.037-0.125-0.053c-0.022-0.01-0.045-0.018-0.068-0.027 c-0.043-0.014-0.086-0.029-0.13-0.04c-0.024-0.008-0.05-0.014-0.075-0.02c-0.042-0.01-0.084-0.02-0.127-0.028 c-0.029-0.005-0.06-0.01-0.09-0.014c-0.039-0.005-0.078-0.01-0.116-0.013c-0.037-0.004-0.075-0.005-0.113-0.006 c-0.025-0.001-0.049-0.004-0.074-0.004h-7.828c-1.202,0-2.175,0.972-2.175,2.171v48.635c0,1.199,0.973,2.171,2.175,2.171h7.828 c1.202,0,2.176-0.972,2.176-2.171V26.542l22.316,30.137c0.153,0.217,0.34,0.396,0.549,0.537c0.008,0.006,0.017,0.011,0.026,0.017 c0.043,0.03,0.087,0.055,0.133,0.081c0.02,0.012,0.041,0.023,0.062,0.034c0.033,0.019,0.068,0.034,0.103,0.05 c0.035,0.016,0.069,0.032,0.105,0.045c0.023,0.009,0.045,0.017,0.067,0.025c0.048,0.017,0.097,0.032,0.147,0.047 c0.011,0.003,0.021,0.005,0.031,0.008c0.178,0.048,0.365,0.075,0.557,0.075h7.829c1.2,0,2.175-0.972,2.175-2.171V6.792 C108.389,5.593,107.414,4.621,106.214,4.621"></path>
```

and this

```
<polygon fill="#231F1F" points="207.065,113.178 207.065,90.966 211.022,90.966 211.022,102.62 216.199,96.901 220.425,96.901 214.127,103.869 221.216,113.178 216.685,113.178 211.022,105.787 211.022,113.178  "/>
```

this code that show image shaped letter.

and my question is what tools that they used?

Comment: See [Tools for SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Tools_for_SVG).

Comment: @showdev you mean that, first create image SVG then convert to code?

Comment: The code looks like [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG) elements. You'll create the SVG by generating that code.